# USB data cable that doubles up as a USB storage device

Tags: usb, cables, assembly, android, iphone

Is it possible to create an USB to micro USB (or lightning) cable that has storage built into it?

So if it's plugged into a computer with no phone, the computer recognizes it as a regular USB storage device. If it's plugged into a computer with a phone attached, it only acts as a regular USB data cable.

If is possible, is it difficult to do?

Comment: Certainly it's possible, and it should be no more difficult than any it her usb composite device-- straightforward if you have the right tools and experience, and difficult otherwise

Comment: @ScottSeidman Is there any way you could provide instructions on how to do it?

Comment: As described, this is a bad idea, as connecting a phone while the storage volume is mounted would cause it to disappear without a chance for filesystem state to be flushed, which is likely to lead to data corruption sooner or later.  Making a working product would require putting thought into the mode switch rules to avoid this type of issue.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Would there be any difference if I said that the cable didn't need to switch from being storage to a transfer cable when it's plugged into a phone, rather it can be both at the same time. (i.e. Is that any easier)

Answer (score 1):

Possible and difficult:

You will need an IC that can do USB storage, flash memory for that IC, and a USB switch IC.  And then write some code that will switch the data lines from cable to storage IC.

Comment: I noticed that this product has been able to do it: http://www.symlis.com/features/ ....do you think this was done via the method you described above?

Comment: No idea - get one, open it, and let us know!

Comment: If you can find their patent they mention, it will describe how it's done.